# Как преобразовать массив для использования в json

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как массив вида

```
goods: [ Object({ id: 1, title: 'Пицца', count: 2, price: '500.00' }) ]
```

преобразовать в вид

```
goods: [ Object({ title: 'Пицца', count: 2 }) ]
```

для дальнейшего формирования Json?

Пытаюсь циклом пройти

```
function sendRequest(name, phone, address, goods, sum)
    {

    let data = {
        client: name + " " + phone, 
        goods: [], 
        order: {address: "ул. " + address.street + ", дом " + address.house + ", " + address.entrance + " подъезд, " + address.floor + " этаж, кв." + address.flat, 
        sum: sum},
    };


    for(let i = 0; i <= goods.length; i++){
        data.goods.push(goods[i]["title", "count"]);
    }

    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    return jsonData;
}
```

Но ругаются автотесты `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')"`.

Где я накосячила?

Заранее огромное спасибо

Comment: Вы куда-то не туда пошли) вам нужно из исходного массива оставить только title и count? или к уже существующему массиву добавить нужные атрибуты? + goods[i]["title", "count"] запись так работать не будет

Comment: читай https://learn.javascript.ru, раздел массивы и методы массива:::
{} => это обект, не надо делать так Object({}):::
метод filter то что тебе нужно:::
ошибка возникает ты вызываеш [undefined].count, то есть то что перед точкой не имеет значения.

Comment: не спорю, что не туда. JS только начала изучать. Нужно из исходного массива оставить только title и count.   Почитала про массивы и методы - https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods . Но только больше запуталась. в результате  у меня должен получиться json  вида  например:
// {
//    "data": {
//      "client": "Иван +7(987)65-43-210",
//      "order": {
//        "address": "ул. Ленина, дом 2, 4 подъезд, 5 этаж, кв. 53",
//        "sum": 900
//       },
//       "goods": [
//         {
//           "title": "Пицца",
//           "count": 2
//         }
//      ]
//    }
// }

Answer (score 1):

У метода `stringify` есть параметр replacer, с его помощью в том числе можно указать какие ключи включать в json.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#using_an_array_as_replacer

```js
let obj = {
           goods:
              [
                { id: 1, title: 'Пицца', count: 2, price: '500.00' },
                { id: 2, title: 'Хотдог', count: 3, price: '200.00' }
              ]
           }

let json = JSON.stringify(obj,['goods','title','count'])

console.log(json)
```